# Measure Battery voltage with ADC in noisy environment and supply circuit from that same battery. single ended/differential mode?

Tags: batteries, adc, differential

need your opinion:

Want to build a device that is able to measure a battery voltage and send results wirelessly every x minutes.
The Battery has nominal 24 volts. Batteries are in a yacht (e.g. engine batt, generator batt, service batt, bow thruster and stern thruster batt).
The ADC could be a ADS1115. circuit should be powered by that same battery. I made two variants shown below and like to hear your input what would be the most robust solution in terms of accuracy and resistance against noise.

Variant 1: single ended mode
The battery would feed an LDO which makes VCC 3.3v, and to measure the Batt voltage it is divided to get 0..3V range, and feed that to A0 of the ADC which is configured to single ended measurement.

[image: single ended mode]

Variant 2:
ADC used in differential mode. Batt GND and plus are fed into a voltage divider which makes a voltage of 0..3V, which is symmetrical within but not touching GND and VCC levels of the ADC. That is fed into A0 and A1 of the ADC and measured in differential mode.
All GNDs of uC, ADC, LDO, Battery are connected to each other as in first variant.
Question is which variant gives more resilience against noise on the power lines to which the battery is connected, or if there is an idea to make it better than shown.

[image: differential mode]

A third option I thought of was to power the circuit with two AA batteries (it draws only 1-2 µA in sleep mode) to be independent of the Battery GND, however the measurement anyway would only work if GND reference of the signal and of the ADC are the same, so Battery powering does not make an improvement.

Thank you!!

Comment: Markus, that's a lot of design and testing work you'll need to do, to resist the noise and spikes on the 24V line.  Are you aware there are commercially available wireless battery monitors (WiFi or Bluetooth connectivity) that support 24V batteries?

Comment: I see little value in using differential inputs. The design challenges will include noise and spikes, which you can suppress with filtering, and keeping the quiescent battery drain as low as possible.